# Safari - Jumpy animation in Safari using jQuery Animate - Fine in FF & Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, safari

I'm trying to animate the opening and closing of a menu. I'm doing this in two places on the site. One place is working fine and the other place is not.

http://rob-s-williams.com/development/

For example, here I am opening and closing the menu by clicking 'Project info' (navigated to Ben Eine project)

Great, works fine in Safari.

However, on the homepage when I am trying to open and close the menu - in Safari it's jumpy and not very smooth. Please see this page below and click on projects, about or contact (in Safari)

I am doing this the same way for each.

For example, initially I set the element like this

```
.mm-info {
    width: 400px;
    z-index: 1;
    left: -1000px;
    background: #fff;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    height: 100%;
}
```

then when I click on the element I am

```
var mainmenu_info_panel = $(mainmenu_info);
    mainmenu_info_panel.animate({"left":"0px"}, "slow").addClass('visible');
    $(mainmenu_projects_panel).fadeIn(1000);
```

Exact code can be found here 
https://github.com/twotwentytwo/rob-s-williams/blob/master/scripts/modules/menu.js
Line 73

**Please note I am yet to refactor some of this code, so yes it's a little bit repetitive and needs serious refactoring.**

I seem to be doing the same thing in 2 places, one works one doesn't.

I have tried :

- Removing the elements on the homepage, apart from the menu items and some test content in the menu and this doesn't work
- I replaced the animation with CSS animation - that didn't work.

I'm at a bit of a loss.

Anyone able to help please?

Comment: Safari, which version? Which OS?

Comment: Mac, Safari 5.1.10. Also, when testing on iPhone 4 and 5 - not sure of exact version of these as I'm running iOS emulation through Xcode

Comment: Mac, then i couldn't help you but isn't Safari 5.1.0 outdated?

Comment: That's true, I believe the bug is also present on the latest version of Safari. I'll try and get exact version numbers. Thank you.

Comment: I could be very wrong, and i can not test. But have you tested the animation with the class "visible" attached all the time?

Comment: Hmm, I'll have a look at that now Nico.

Comment: Yes, added it all the time. Actually made me realise I do not need the 'visible' class. It wasn't doing anything... However, interestingly I removed this redundant class to no effect. I then tried to animate with CSS transition, and the juddering issue is still there. I'm thinking perhaps it's not to do with .animate() in jQuery or the CSS animation.

Comment: Maybe it is an easing issue. You set `.mm-info { left: -1000px }` have you tried just set it to `-400px`, the actual size of the menu? You could also try if the issue persists with linear easing. But for now i've guessed enough. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks, I've made that change and unfortunately it still seems to be there. Good point though about the difference between 1000px and 400px. Thanks for your help.